# SQL SELECT products which are available in multiple countries

Tags: sql, count, distinct, having

i have this table of fruits with market and prices (table is actually just an excerpt)

```
Product Market  Price
Apple   UK  4
Apple   DE  5
Apple   US  4
Apple   IT  3
Banana  US  2
Orange  UK  1
Kiwi    ES  3
Kiwi    DE  10
Kiwi    US  12
Kiwi    UK  11
Cucumb  IT  5
Cucumb  DE  4
Cucumb  UK  3
Peach   IT  12
Peach   DE  10
Peach   UK  10
Peach   US  11
```

Now i only want to select (or group) products which are available in all four markets DE, UK, IT and US. Which should result in this table:

```
Product Market  Price
Apple   UK  4
Apple   DE  5
Apple   US  4
Apple   IT  3
Peach   IT  12
Peach   DE  10
Peach   UK  10
Peach   US  11
```

I have tried it with group by+having+Count Distinct, but it does not work. See below

```
SELECT
market, product, AVG(price) as pr
FROM
    fruits
WHERE       
    market IN (DE, IT, UK, US)
GROUP BY
    market, product
HAVING Count (DISTINCT market=4)
```

i guess that i'm using the count distinct in a wrong way. 
Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Having - condition `Count (DISTINCT market=4)`should be rather:

```
SELECT
market, product, AVG(price) as pr
FROM
    fruits
WHERE       
    market IN (DE, IT, UK, US)
GROUP BY
    market, product
HAVING Count (DISTINCT market) = 4
```

Comment: I understand the answer, but not the upvote.  `count(distinct market)` is always going to be `1` in this query.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have duplicate countries for a product.  I would recommend  simple window function:

```
select f.*
from (select f.*, count(*) over (partition by product) as cnt
      from fruits f
      where market in ('DE', 'IT', 'UK', 'US')
     ) f
where cnt = 4;
```